# Using Game Maker Language, how do I isolate text in a specific HTML tag in a file into its own variable?

Tags: html, game-maker

This may be a little different from most questions, because it deals with Game Maker Language.

What my program does:

> Downloads an HTML page
>   Reads the page into a variable
>   Reads text in the first of a specific HTML tag

The last part is my problem.  Under the first tag `<h3><a HREF="dynamic content">TEXT HERE</a></h3>` is the text I need to retrieve.  Now, there are many of those lines in the document, I must get the first one.  Also, one problem is that the HREF content does change every time this site is updated (Why I put 'dynamic content' there).

How do I process the variable to eliminate all text around the h3 tags, and how do I get the text data into its own variable without any clutter?

This is complicated in GML, I know.  Much thanks to anyone who knows how to do this!

Comment: With the code here, I have fixed my own problem.  Hopefully this helps someone, sometime.

    //Variable to store original file data
    working=argument0

    //Isolate string to h3 hyperlink
    position = string_pos("<h3><a>",working)
    working = string_delete(working,1,position)
    
    //Delete all content after the version number
    position = string_pos("</a></h3>",working)
    working = string_delete(working,position, string_length(working) )
    
    return working
}

Comment: You can post your own answer below and accept it when you can (48 hours if I remember correctly), so others can see and hopefully be helped when they encounter a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code function here, I have finally fixed my own problem. Hopefully this helps someone, sometime.

```
//Variable to store original file data 
working = argument0

//Isolate string to h3 hyperlink 
position = string_pos("<h3><a>",working) 
working = string_delete(working,1,position) 

//Delete all content after the version number 
position = string_pos("</a></h3>",working) 
working = string_delete(working,position, string_length(working) ) 

return working
```